# Function Arguments dialog executes UDF when all non-optional arguments are filled

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have a function `foo(bar as String, Optional baz as String)`, that does some really heavy lifting (connecting to database, etc ...). The problem we're seeing is that when the *Function Arguments* dialog is displayed (by clicking on *Fx* icon next to the formula to bring up that dialog) and the user puts a value of `bar`, Excel decides to execute the function right away, without waiting for the user to enter a value of `baz` or to press *Ok*.

Is there a way to detect in UDF that the user is using this dialog to basically not do anything?

In my screenshot, you can see that Excel shows *Formula result* in the bottom left corner once value for `Bar` is entered.

[image]

Comment: I think the only thing that's available to you in the function is is `Application.Caller`, and that shows the cell containing the function in both cases (direct entry in the cell, or using the function arguments dialog)

Comment: Won't it be a cell in both cases? You still have to select a cell before clicking on that icon.

Comment: Sorry just realized that you meant the same thing in both cases.. Is there a way to detect if that dialog is open somehow?

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of, though there may be some API method which would allow detecting that dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my UDF page:
[Excel User-defined Functions](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm)

To detect when a VBA UDf is being called from the function wizard you can add this code to the UDF

```
If (Not Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls(1).Enabled) Then Exit Function
```

This code depends on the fact that when using the function wizard most icons in the toolbars are disabled.

A solution is also possible by using the Windows API to check if the Function Wizard window is showing and has the same process ID as the current Excel process.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so:
Use a standard module named: "m01_CONFIG"

```
'--- Here below declaration of 
' variables:

Global oExcel As
Excel.Application

'--- Add that procedure as 
' subroutine to display the needed information about the
' arguments and their use:

Public Sub ArgumentsDescription_Add()

  Set oExcel = Excel.application

  With oExcel

       .MacroOption
        Macro:= _
         "mfx_strPASSFAIL", _
        ArgumentDescriptions:= 
        Array(
      "Range that contains Mark")

  End With

  Set oExcel = Nothing

End Sub

' -- Here below an UDFs Function
' just for e.g.

Public Function 
mfx_strPASSFAIL(ByRef fx_lngMark&) As String

 '--- Here below a condition:

  If fx_lngMark >= 50 Then

     Let mfx_strPASSFAIL = "Pass"
  Else

     Let mfx_strPASSFAIL = "Fail"

  End if

End Function

' --- HERE above is a way to  
' create description of any
' UDFs Function that could help
' the interface users to grasp
' the useful of it.
```